# How to model fixed-size weekly schedule with Prisma and PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, prisma

I'm using Prisma connected to a PostgreSQL database. A user needs to be able to select the days and times in which they are available, like in the image below.

[image: Weekly schedule]

Given this is a one-to-one relationship (i.e. a user has only one schedule and one schedule pertains to only one user) and that a weekly schedule is a fixed-size structure (i.e. 7 days with 17 hours each), I'm wondering how to efficiently model this in a database.

This is my current solution (in JSON):

```
{
    id: 'some-id',
    email: 'myemail@email.com',
    passwordHash: 'somehash',
    schedule: {
        monday: {
            slot_7: true,
            slot_8: true,
            ...
            slot_23: true
        },
        tuesday: {
            slot_7: true,
            slot_8: true,
            ...
            slot_23: true
        },
        ...
        sunday: {
            slot_7: true,
            slot_8: true,
            ...
            slot_23: true
        }
    }
}
```

Having `monday ... sunday` and `slot_7 ... slot_23` feels dirty. This becomes obvious when rendering this data on the frontend by the fact that the frontend needs to access each object key explicitly instead of using a loop.

This feels like the job for a fixed-size bidimensional (7x17) array, but there are a few disadvantages I'm not sure how to solve:

1. Neither PostgreSQL nor Prisma support fixed-size arrays. I could enforce/verify the array's dimensions in code, but I feel like the responsibility to enforce the data structure falls onto the database.
2. Giving the days of the week and the time slots specific names like 'monday' and 'slot_7' ensures they are explicitly identified. Changing the days of the week into an array of length 7 doesn't explicitize the week starts on Monday (it could start on Sunday), and changing the time slots from `slot_7 ... slot_23` to an array of length 17 also doesn't explicitize the first one starts at 7AM. This lack of explicitness creates an assumption in the code. If we change the database model and add another time slot, the first one now starting at 6AM, the code may still render the time slots but they will be wrong, because the code assumes the first item in the array pertains to the 7AM time slot. When we have explicit keys, even if we add a `slot_6` to the database, the code will still work correctly.

The best of both worlds in terms of having both the efficiency of an array and the explicitness of named keys would be a dictionary, but given ([as far as I know](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14106)) neither Prisma nor PostgreSQL support native dictionaries as data structures, is there a way to solve both challenges at once?

## Update 1:

Prisma doesn't yet support [dictionaries](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14106), but we could use an array of objects that identify themselves, like so:

```
{
    id: 'some-id',
    email: 'myemail@email.com',
    passwordHash: 'somehash',
    schedule: [
        {
            day: 'monday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'tuesday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        ...
        {
            day: 'sunday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

This way we have the best of both worlds in terms of the efficiency of an array and the explicitness of named fields, but the downside is that it is possible for the arrays to have duplicated objects:

```
{
    id: 'some-id',
    email: 'myemail@email.com',
    passwordHash: 'somehash',
    schedule: [
        {
            day: 'monday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'monday', //  duplicated identification
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: false },
                { slot: 8, free: false },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        ...
        {
            day: 'monday', //  duplicated identification
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: false },
                { slot: 8, free: false },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: false },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Given this suboptimal solution, the only thing left is to make sure there are no duplicate keys by using the unique keyword (in both SQL and Prisma).

## Update 2:

For those looking for a similar solution, here's what I've came up with:

```
model User {
   id           String          @id @default(uuid())
   createdAt    DateTime        @default(now())
   updatedAt    DateTime        @updatedAt
   email        String          @unique
   passwordHash String
   schedule     DailySchedule[]
}

model DailySchedule {
   id     String  @id @default(uuid())
   day    String
   times  Times[]
   user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
   userId String

   @@unique([userId, day])
}

model Times {
   id              String        @id @default(uuid())
   time            Decimal
   free            Boolean
   dailySchedule   DailySchedule @relation(fields: [dailyScheduleId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
   dailyScheduleId String

   @@unique([dailyScheduleId, time])
}
```

This ensures the following structure without repetition:

```
{
    id: 'some-id',
    email: 'myemail@email.com',
    passwordHash: 'somehash',
    schedule: [
        {
            day: 'monday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'tuesday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
        ...
        {
            day: 'sunday',
            timeslots: [
                { slot: 7, free: true },
                { slot: 8, free: true },
                ...
                { slot: 23, free: true },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: The relational way to do this would be to have a separate table that holds an available day of the week as an int and an hour as an int.  This table would have up to 112 rows for each employee each week.  The key to this table would be employee ID and a date that signifies the start of a work week.  The two ints and the date would have a unique index to prevent duplicate rows.

Comment: *The efficiency of an array*. Not so much in a RDBMS. Arrays there tend to be inefficient at best; often very much so.  @GilbertLeBlanc presents a much better arrangement than an array.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. What makes @Gilbert Le Blanc's solution the relational way to do it? Wouldn't my updated solution also be relational? What are the distinguishing criteria between the two?